# Prestashop installation error

Tags: failed-installation, prestashop-1.7, error-code

I am facing a problem when I install prestashop in wamp 
When until module installation it show 
Error-500 
I have search for many ways but all is just stopped at the install demonstrate data no one
Facing problem in module install 
Can I know how to fix it?

Comment: Install XAMP & then install prestashop in that.

Comment: Tried xampp and damp same

Answer (score 0):

Install XAMP & then install prestashop in that.